# Are my answers valid?(simple proof, convergence, sequences)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am doing questions from a textbook that doesn't provide me with answers so I would be very grateful if someone could let me know if I am on the right lines with these answers:

1) Let $ k,l $ be two non negative integers. Show $ min(2k,2l)\leq k+l$

I showed this with two cases.

Case 1: Suppose $k=l$ then trivially $k+l=2k=2l$ so $min(2k,2l)=k+l$

Case 2: Suppose $k\geq l$ without loss of generality, then $2k>2l$ so $min(2k,2l)=2l$ and $2l=l+l \leq l+k$. Hence $min(2k,2l) \leq k+l $

2) Let n bet natural numbers. Suppose $(a_n)$ is a convergent sequence with limit L. Suppose also that, for some N (Natural number) and real K, $a_n$>K whenever $n >N$. Show $L \geq K$.

I did this by contradiction.

Suppose $K>L$ then for n>N $|a_n-K| < |a_n-L|< \epsilon$ for $\epsilon >0$ (definition of convergence).

this implies that K is the limit of the sequence i.e K=L which is a contradiction so $K \leq L$

3) Suppose $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence and that $(a_n)$ does not converge to 0. Show that there is a subsequence $(a_k)$ converging to a non-zero limit.

I said: $|(a_n)|<M$ because it is bounded.Let $\epsilon = M/2$ so there exists an N such that for n>N  $|a_n-0|$>M/2. If there is a $|a_n|>M/2$ then there is a subsequence $|a_k-0|>M/2$ for all k. so $(a_k)$ does not converge to 0. But Bolzano Weierstrass says every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence so we can conclude that there is a non-zero limit to the subsequence.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1)$ What you do is fine, but your second case can be modified slightly to include the first case.

$(2)$ You have the right idea, but more should be done.  What I mean is just because $a_n>K$ for $n\geq N$ doesn't mean $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$ for $n\geq N$.

$(3)$ You didn't use the fact that $\{a_n\}$ doesn't converge to $0$ properly.  To do this, you should write "there is some $\varepsilon>0$ and a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $|a_{n_k}-0|\geq\varepsilon$ for all $k$.  Other than that, it seems like you have the right idea.